# reading excel file into visual studio (c#) and matching with database(in visual studio) write matched results into word document

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, ms-office

I am working on words matching project. after matlab processing I got excel file

```
1 2
2 5
3 10
4  3
5  7
.  .
.  .
```

the first  column describe the word no and second column related to reference word no in database.

let database include

```
1  AMNBBHHH
2  I
3  PRIYANGA    
5  AM
.  .
.  .
10  SAHAN
.  .
.  .
```

so that the result should be write in word document as follow,

```
I AM SAHAN PRIYANGA . . .
```

so that I want to suggestions to

- creating database that include words and reference no
- read excel file into visual studio and matched with database
- write them back into word document

***note by***

- I am using visual studio 2013 and Microsoft 2010 and going to use
  windows form application in visual studio with button ( to submit
  load file into visual studio).
- around 200 unique words in database

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use excel?

Comment: using Matlab I have write results into a excel file that's why it is used

Comment: I am sure you can write your results in to a more simple file structure like csv. That will eliminate your problem of reading an excel file in C#.

Comment: so if it is then what shall i do ??????                however finally it should be end up with word document!!!

Comment: Use [this](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) for reading excel and [this](https://docx.codeplex.com/) for reading/writing MSWord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is little incomplete but I am trying to answer your needs with the best guess of mine:

**Choice of Database**

- You haven't mentioned your choice of database. Do you have a database
  server hosted in a central location or it is part of your windows
  form application itself, something like Sqlite?
- You haven't mentioned the number of unique words you are expecting to
  be stored in a key value pair, if there are going to be a million of
  words then you would need some kind of partitioning if it is RDBMS
  table or you may consider something like Redis or Memcache based data
  store for fast retrieval

**Reading Excel File**

- Since you have a well formatted excel file, I would recommend reading the file using (ADO.Net) Microsoft OLEDB or ODBC Data Provider. This will help you in staying away from Excel Library wrappers in your Windows Forms Application and will avoid some memory leaks
- In case you don't want to use ADO.Net Data Providers, there open source libraries for reading excel files. I would prefer that.
- Second part of this problem is to read corresponding strings and store them in some C# object. The choice of solution may vary by your choice of database. If you prefer to go with Redis/ Memcache based database store, then I would probably read each row from Excel, find the index of word and access the word stored in datastore and keep forming the sentence. In case it's RDBMS, we may have to look at more complex solution in order to appropriately store and access the data.

**Writing into Word Doc**

- Please prefer to use OpenXML Format for writing back to Word Doc, this will help you in staying away from the Office Libraries in your Windows Forms Application.